# Lighting is too bright and cant seem to make it work

Tags: modeling, shaders, lighting

Blender newbie here. I recently finished the donut tutorial (I know, I know, but its actually helped me a lot). I'm trying to follow the tutorial again, but with my own object (a cupcake). I'm having some problems with the light, I've deleted it multiple times and tried again but its still super bright. There is also no shadow on the plane. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thought I'd try here before redoing it. Thanks[image][image][image]

[image]

Comment: did you try to decrease the power? to e.g. 1 W ? If you wanna have an accurate answer pls provide blend file, so we can help you out. This could have different reasons. To upload your blend file just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your response, I've attached the blend file (and thank you for showing me how to do that!) as 1 W still seems off.

Comment: weird because it's not too bright for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the main issue might be only because your light is pretty near to your donut. So either you can move your light more far away or your enter in lighting power e.g. a 0.1 so you get this:

[image]

[image]

if i move your light to this location:

[image]

i got this result, even with 10 W power:

[image]

Comment: thank you so so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: if my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is not only the distance from the cupcake, but also the size. The Watt values for lights are trying to recreate realistic lighting which means, the size of things matters a lot, too.

Your cupcake has a diameter of about 0.016 m, that's just 1.6 cm which is quite small. So you have a very tiny cupcake with a light source very close to it. So this is how the render looks on my computer:

[image: tiny cupcake]

But if I take all objects including the camera and scale them by 5, so that they all get bigger while remaining in the same relation to each other, suddenly the 1 W light isn't so bright anymore. It is still very close to the cupcake, though. The cupcake is now 8 cm in diameter, maybe a bit too large now but you get the idea:

[image: larger cupcake]

That's why one of the tips which Blenderguru Andrew always gives for realistic renders is: use real world dimensions.

Comment: Thank you! Simple error, but you taught me something!

Comment: @sarm Seemingly not enough to accept the answer :D